# JSON response print

Tags: json, ajax

I have a ajax request script with post method using body value, what I want is, to print the response value.

```
 $('#my-form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apiurl.com/users',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF8',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'api-key': 'judmkd895849438'
      },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { "firstname": $('#firstname').val(), "lastname": $('#lastname').val() },
        success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    });
 });
```

and the form script is:

```
<form id='my-form'>
    <div><input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' placeholder='Firstname' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' placeholder='Lastname' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>

<!-- where the response will be displayed -->
    <div id="response">
    <pre></pre>
</div>
```

but nothing display on screen, anyone know why?

thanks

Comment: There is no `<pre>` inside your `#response` div so `$('#response pre')` has nothing to update.

Comment: I added but still nothing appears

Comment: What happens if `console.log(data);` inside the `success` callback? Does anything get logged to the console?

Comment: Hi @phuzi, tried it but nothing show on console also. But if I removed the $('#my-form').submit(function () { the console log display with null data

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call is succeeding? If so, are you confident that there is a JSON reponse?

Comment: I am thinking that the form field value not parse to the body in ajax, is hard to me for tracing since no error appeared on console :(. Is there any better way to get the value from the form data and parse to ajax request as body

Comment: Try looking in your browser's dev tools specifically the network tab to see what is being sent and received by the browser.

Comment: Hi @phuzi isnot only record Waiting. I am not too understand about the network part as your mentioned :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189930/discussion-between-phuzi-and-bireon).

Comment: The real problem is submitting a form without a **preventDefault**, that's make the page reload so you'll never see what the ajax is retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

As Roy stated, you'll need to prevent the browser from submitting the form. You'll have to prevent the default event from firing as you're handling it via an AJAX request.

```
$('#my-form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apiurl.com/users',
...
```